# Externalise strings problem after converting project to Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, internationalization

I just converted an old Java project to Maven and rearranged the source folders to fit the Maven scheme: `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, etc.

I moved the messages files from the `java` folders to the `resources` folders and everything was ok.

Now I want to make some changes and externalise some strings. Eclipse externalises the strings to new messages files in the `java` folder and not the existing messages files in the `resources`folder.

How can I tell eclipse about the Maven structure?

Comment: Have you created the appropriate package structure in `src/main/resources` ?

Comment: You could import project while clicking on the pom file.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes - the messages are displayed correctly. The problem occurs when I externalise strings after making changes.

Comment: @SorinPenteleiciuc not sure exactly what you mean. What I have already done is to delete the project from the workspace and import as Maven project. That didn't help.

Comment: If you think there is an issue while importing the project you need to delete the files in your project like `.project`, `.classpath` and `.settings` which are generated by Eclipse. The best is to have everything in Git and correctly configured `.gitignore` which means you can do by `git clean -fdx` and make an import into Eclipse.